# Locating a View File in An HMVC approach

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I am using codeigniter for my application and developing with HMVC approach with the added package here:

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

I have a custom template I created for my views and in my content view have the following lines:

```
if ((!isset($page_view)) || (is_null($page_view)) || (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/backend/' .     $this->cms_template . '/cpanel/pages/' . $page_view . '.php')))
{
    $this->load->view('backend/' . $this->cms_template . '/cpanel/template/page_unknown_view');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('backend/' . $this->cms_template . '/cpanel/pages/' . $page_view);
}
```

?>

This works when there are views in the folder but since some of my views will be in a different folder for this HMVC approach it always shows up as my unknown page file. How should I modify so that it works with this approach.

**EDIT:** Let me try and rephrase all of this. This is my file system...

```
/application/views/backend/{templatename}/cpanel/index_view
/application/views/backend/{templatename}/cpanel/template/(header.php, footer.php, content.php)
/application/modules/users/controllers/users
/application/modules/users/views/users_view
```

Lets say the users controller loads the cpanel view as its main view page which loads the three template pages. Being the header, footer and content page. Inside of the content page it performs the if statement as seen above. It gets sent a variable that finds out which controller specific view to load. IN this instance I want it to load the users_view file. So with my if statement I need it to find out if its a file that exists somewhere in that module's folder.

Does this help at all?

Comment: are you sure about your question? don't you have some other information that might be useful? I'm not following well with your description to the problem!!

Comment: The file_exists function is looking for the view files in Codeigniter's native view location folder but I have an added on third party plugin and need to figure out how I can apply that to the it as well.

Comment: yes I got that, but what I'm missing is what do you need.

Comment: How I should modify my if statement.

Comment: what you mean by:This works when there are views in the folder but since some of my views will be in a different folder...
do you mean by **"different folder"** a different module?

Comment: Please review my edit in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access a different module view you can access it in this way:

```
$this->load->view('module_name/view_file_name');
```

If its needed in all the modules,can also place it in main view i.e. applications view

and you can simply access them using:

```
$this->load->view('view_file_name');
```

From any module.

Comment: Good answer but please review my post edit for further explaination.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the OP question, it is about checking if a view file exists before trying to load it

Eg : check that a module have a 'my_template.php' file before trying to load it.

---

First of all, the `load->view()` function checks every `views` folder it has in its loaded path

Given the paths :

*application/

application/modules/xxxxx/

application/modules/yyyyy/*

> `$this->load->view('my_template');`
>
> Will search for a `my_template.php` file in all the `views/` folders
>
> *application/views/my_template.php
>
>   application/modules/xxxxx/views/my_template.php
>
>   application/modules/yyyyy/views/my_template.php*

-

> `$this->load->view('my_module/my_template');`
>
> Will search for a `my_template.php` file in all the `views/my_modules/` folders
>
> *application/views/my_module/my_template.php
>
>   application/modules/xxxxx/views/my_module/my_template.php
>
>   application/modules/yyyyy/views/my_module/my_template.php*

so be aware that if you want to call the view of a specific module through

`$this->load->view('x_module/my_template');`

you have to create a 'x_module/' subfolder either in the main views folder or in the module views folder :

- `application/views/x_module/my_template.php`
- `application/modules/x_module/views/x_module/my_template.php`

**!! Attention** : If several module have the same subfolder `views/x_module/` or if you put your file directly in the views folder of the module, you could have problems while setting another module with the same filename in the views folder

> `$this->load-views('my_template');` <- ambiguous
>
> `application/modules/x_module/views/my_template.php`
>   `application/modules/y_module/views/my_template.php`

-

> `$this->load-views('my_module/my_template');` <- ambiguous
>
> `application/modules/x_module/views/my_module/my_template.php`
>   `application/modules/my_module/views/my_template.php`

-

> `$this->load-views('x_module/my_template');` <- Crystal Clear !
>
> `application/modules/x_module/views/x_module/my_template.php`
>   `application/modules/y_module/views/y_module/my_template.php`

---

This said, the problem here is the checking of the existence of a template in the loaded path, hence the if statement construction.

I ran across this problem with HMVC & CI and modules, because `$this->load->view()` throws an error if the file does not exists, and sometimes you want just to check if a file is available without considering an error if it is missing.

So my solution was to check for the file in the loaded path of CI

```
// set the view I want to load->view()
$relative_view_path = 'x_module/my_template.php';

// retrieve an array of the paths loaded by CI
$pack_path = $this->load->get_package_paths( TRUE );

// set the checker to false
$can_load = FALSE;

// loop the loaded paths
foreach( $pack_path as $path )
{
    // Check if the file exists in the path
    // $path has a ending slash !
    if( file_exists( $path.$relative_view_path ) ) $can_load = TRUE; 
}

// and finally 
if( $can_load == TRUE ) $this->load->view($relative_view_path);
```

Hope that helps